# Yii2 Get the specific attribute of the relationship model

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have 2 models Onlinelearning and Onlinelearningreviews with the HAS MANY relationship. I want to get specific attribute of the Onlinelearningreviews model.

Onlinelearning attributes: `ID, Title, URL, Description, GradeAge`

Onlinelearningreviews attributes: `ID, OnlinelearningID, Rating, Comments`

**Model Onlinelearning:**

```
public function getOnlinelearningreviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Onlinelearningreviews::className(), ['OnlineLearningID' => 'ID']);
}
```

**Model Onlinelearningreviews:**

```
 public function getOnlineLearning()
 {
        return $this->hasOne(Onlinelearning::className(), ['ID' => 'OnlineLearningID']);
 }
```

I want get `Title, URL, Description, GradeAge and Rating` attributes.

Following works:

```
Onlinelearning::find()->select(['Title','URL','Description','GradeAge'])->with('onlinelearningreviews')->asArray()->all();
```

But when I specify Rating it gives me error

```
Onlinelearning::find()->select(['Title','URL','Description','GradeAge','onlinelearningreviews.Rating'])->with('onlinelearningreviews')->asArray()->all();
```

How to get only **Rating** attribute from the Onlinelearningreviews model? I don't want other attributes.

`Onlinelearning::find()->with(['onlinelearningreviews'])->asArray()->all()` prints:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 1
                [Title] => Udemy
                [URL] => http://www.google.com
                [Description] => Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                [GradeAge] => 2nd to 5th Grade
                [AddedOn] => 2015-03-20 00:00:00
                [LastModifiedOn] => 2015-03-20 00:00:00
                [onlinelearningreviews] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [ID] => 1
                                [ParentID] => 1
                                [OnlineLearningID] => 1
                                [Rating] => 3.5
                                [PositiveComments] => It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. .
                                [NegativeComments] => 
                                [AddedOn] => 
                                [LastModifiedOn] => 
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [ID] => 2
                                [ParentID] => 1
                                [OnlineLearningID] => 1
                                [Rating] => 3.5
                                [PositiveComments] => It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. 
                                [NegativeComments] => 
                                [AddedOn] => 
                                [LastModifiedOn] => 
                            )

                    )

            )
)
```

And

```
Onlinelearning::find()
        ->select(['Title','URL','Description','GradeAge'])
        ->with([
            'onlinelearningreviews' => function ($query) {
                /* @var $query yii\db\ActiveQuery */

                $query->select('Rating');
            },
        ])
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
```

prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Udemy
            [URL] => http://www.google.com
            [Description] => Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            [GradeAge] => 2nd to 5th Grade
            [onlinelearningreviews] => Array
                (
                )

        )
)
```

Comment: @arogachev: I need all attributes from the Onlinelearning and only Rating attribute from the Onlinelearningreviews. Dont want to fetch unnecessary attribute which I have no use.

Comment: Do you want average rating or all the ratings ?...

Comment: @soju: I need all ratings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible like that:

```
Onlinelearning::find()
    ->select(['Title','URL','Description','GradeAge'])
    ->with([
        'onlinelearningreviews' => function ($query) {
            /* @var $query \yii\db\ActiveQuery */

            $query->select('Rating');
        },
    ])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

See [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait.html#with%28%29-detail) on how to customize relation queries in `with()`.

And if you want to select all attributes from `Onlinelearning` model you can omit `select` part:

```
->select(['Title','URL','Description','GradeAge'])
```

**Update:**

Seems like you should include connected attributes in both models:

```
->select(['ID', 'Title','URL','Description','GradeAge'])
```

and

```
$query->select(['OnlinelearningID', 'Rating']);
```

Otherwise the exception about `Undefinex index` will be thrown.

Comment: I am not getting any error but the array is empty. I have added the output to the question.

Comment: Updated the answer with remark. But it's weird that the empty array was returned, without exception.

Comment: Nope still getting the empty array

Comment: Tested it, it's working for me. Will try to investigate it deeper later.

Comment: Forgot to include ID is select. Silly mistake. After that it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: @arogachev this was spot on what I was looking for. For the field I am imploding the models attribute method return to return only the fields allowed by the model; spot on!